# Error installing Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I'm trying to install Fedora 19. After my computer booted from installation DVD for about 20 minutes, it displays white screen with 'Oh no! Something has gone wrong.' message. I've tried 3 times and it still persists.

Comment: Seriously? That's the message they give you? That's amazingly useless. Do you see anything more informative if you hit `Esc` or `Ctrl+Alt+F1` when it is stuck?

Comment: Full message: A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again. [Log out button]

Comment: And just before that? When you look at the text mode messages (Ctrl+Alt+F1), you should see lines telling you which part of the process is starting. The last one to be started or finished could be informative.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 gives a white-blank screen... I think I'll make a new installation disk and see if it helps.

Comment: Hang on, when exactly is this happening? Are you installing or just running the live session?

Comment: Okay, I inserted the disk, chose 'Start Fedora Live', the loading bubble appears and gone after it's full, Fedora logo comes up and stay on screen for 25 mins then it come to white screen with that message.

Answer (score 2):

### **Never mind this answer. It's not applicable to the actual situation the OP finds himself in.**

Might be this bug from the Fedora 15/16 upgrade returning in the Fedora 18/19 upgrade:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F16_bugs#Starting_GNOME_Shell_fails_after_upgrade_from_Fedora_15_with_color_profile_installed

That bug suggests it's a problem with the gnome-settings-daemon crashing on startup due to mismatched color profiles (which apparently changed between releases, but were not updated properly via the updater). Changing to a different console,as terdon suggested:

```
Crtl+Alt+F1 (or F2 or F3)
```

and then logging into the console will allow you to run the suggested command:

```
su -c 'chcon -R -t icc_data_home_t ~/.local/share/icc'.
```

to fix the color profile.

Another thread: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=272232 suggests it's a problem with come incomplete updates during the upgrade. Switching to another console as above and logging will allow you to look see if that's the case.

You could also switch to KDE at least temporarily as the bug and forum thread both point to GNOME as the source of the problem.

From the console install KDE and kdm:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
sudo yum install kdm
```

then switch to kdm (default is gdm which will work with KDE as well, but you probably need to skip anything gnome related for now (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/KDE):

```
sudo yum install system-switch-displaymanager
sudo system-switch-displaymanager kdm
```

Then reboot.

Comment: The OP is getting this error during install, how will he be able to install packages if the system itself is not installed yet? What does upgrading have t do with anything?

Comment: You're right. In reading the question I though it was a bit fuzzy on exactly when/where the error was happening, but it's not.